# Dax for knowing if a phone number is active or not

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table that has all the calls all my phone numbers make.
Every now and then a phone number becomes inactive (for some reason there is no column showing active/inactive numbers).

I thought I could make a Dax function or a calculated column (I don't know what's better) that will determine what is active or not.

If a number isn't making any calls for the **past 3 weeks** (not including this week) it is a dead number.

but I don't know where to start.
I crated the table:
[image]

each row is a phone number
each column is a week
the values count the amount of answered calls the number made

any ideas?

Comment: How row 3 is active?

Comment: can you put an example of how the data on your source table? (or is it exactly like the table above?)

Comment: @mkRabbani you are right. row 3 is dead.

Comment: @JoaoLeal the data is just like the table above. i have a column offset week for the calander table, a row represents a phone number and the values inside are simply the number of times that phone number made a call